# DLL Plugin is freezing the .exe program

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, dll, exe

I'm making a C++ .dll plug-in for an .exe program. At some point it has to reach into a python algorithm(i chose embed python) and present the solution of that in the plug-in interface.

As i'm not integrating the algorithm yet, i made a simple python script to test the embdedding. So far  everything works.

But when i insert a sleep of 15 seconds in this python script to simulate the algorithm running-time the .exe program freezes for 15 seconds like it was expected. I thought i needed to introduce threads at this point so i followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I) (more explicitly the "Multi-threaded Python embedding" 1st approach part). It still freezes and now i'm stuck for ages in this

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you in advance

Python script,`bridge.py`

```
def test_callsign(b):
fp_txt=open('allomate.txt','w+')
fp_txt.write(b)
time.sleep(15)
fp_txt.write('after sleep')
if b=='MAH543':
    fp_txt.write('\nOne: ')
    fp_txt.close()
    return 1
```

C++ relevant code:

```
void CPythonPlugIn::printtofile(EuroScopePlugIn::CAircraft Aircraft){

    ofstream textfile;
    textfile.open("FP.txt");


    // Loop over the planes
    for ( Aircraft = AircraftSelectFirst (); Aircraft.IsValid (); Aircraft = AircraftSelectNext (Aircraft))
    {
        // Aircraft position
        EuroScopePlugIn :: CAircraftPositionData    Aircraftpos = Aircraft.GetPosition () ;

        EuroScopePlugIn::CAircraftFlightPlan fp=Aircraft.GetFlightPlan();

        //Callsign
        textfile<<Aircraft.GetCallsign()<<endl;

        if(strncmp(Aircraft.GetCallsign(),"MAH543",6)==0){

            char *argv[4]={"PythonPlugIn2","bridge","test_callsign","MAH543"};
            int i;
            SENDTOPY cmd;
            cmd.argc=4;
            for( i = 0; i < NUM_ARGUMENTS; i++ )
            {
                cmd.argv[i] = argv[i];
            }

            handle=(HANDLE) _beginthread(py_embed,0,&cmd);

        };

    WaitForSingleObject(handle,INFINITE);
    textfile.close();
}

void py_embed (void*data){

SENDTOPY* arg=(SENDTOPY*)data;

ofstream textfile3;
textfile3.open("FP_python_embed.txt");

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
PyThreadState *mainThreadState,*myThreadState,*tempState;
PyInterpreterState *mainInterpreterState;

if(arg->argc<3){
    printf("Usage: exe_name python_source function_name\n");
    textfile3<<"Usage: exe_name python_source function_name";
}

//To inform the interpreter about paths to Python run-time libraries
Py_SetProgramName(arg->argv[0]);

// Initialize the Python Interpreter
Py_Initialize();
if( !Py_IsInitialized() ){
    cout<<"Can't initialize"<<endl;
    textfile3<<"Can't initialize"<<endl;
}

// Initialize thread support
PyEval_InitThreads();
// Save a pointer to the main PyThreadState object
mainThreadState = PyThreadState_Get();

// Get a reference to the PyInterpreterState
mainInterpreterState = mainThreadState->interp;

// Create a thread state object for this thread
myThreadState = PyThreadState_New(mainInterpreterState);

// Release global lock
PyEval_ReleaseLock();

// Acquire global lock
PyEval_AcquireLock();

// Swap in my thread state
tempState = PyThreadState_Swap(myThreadState);

// Build the name object
pName = PyString_FromString(arg->argv[1]);
if( !pName ){
    cout<<"Can't build the object "<<endl;
    textfile3<<"Can't build the object "<<endl;
}

// Load the module object
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
if( !pModule ){
    cout<<"Can't import the module "<<endl;
    textfile3<<"Can't import the module "<<endl;
}

// pDict is a borrowed reference 
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
if( !pDict ){
    cout<<"Can't get the dict"<<endl;
    textfile3<<"Can't get the dict"<<endl;
}


// pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, arg->argv[2]);
if( !pFunc || !PyCallable_Check(pFunc) ){
    cout<<"can't get the function"<<endl;
    textfile3<<"can't get the function"<<endl;
}



PyObject *pArgs2, *pValue2;
pArgs2=Py_BuildValue("(s)",arg->argv[3]);
pValue2 = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs2);
textfile3<<PyInt_AsLong(pValue2)<<endl<<" worked1";
textfile3.close();

// Clean up
Py_DECREF(pModule);
Py_DECREF(pName);

// Swap out the current thread
PyThreadState_Swap(tempState);

// Release global lock
PyEval_ReleaseLock();

// Clean up thread state
PyThreadState_Clear(myThreadState);
PyThreadState_Delete(myThreadState);

// Finish the Python Interpreter
Py_Finalize();

_endthread();
};
```

Edit: The three .txt ("allomate", "FP" and "FP_python_embed")  are generated and the information is correct

Comment: so what is the difference between expected output vs actual output? Does your python thread execute at the end of your code, or somewhere in the middle?

Comment: The python thread is executed in the beginning of the loop(over the planes). The difference is none, the only problem is that the .exe program freezes while the python thread is obtaining the solution and that is unacceptable

Comment: why is that unexpected? You call `WaitForSingleObject` right after starting each thread, so your program waits for it to finish before continuing.

Comment: Well, you're absolutely right, i need to not use it.. The thing is, when i delete that `Wait ForSingleObject`the plug-in crashes and i don't know why. The code for the error: "Unhandled exception at 0x1E114A68 (python27.dll) in EuroScope.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFE."

Comment: This error takes me to `thread.c` in this lines: 
`    __try
    {
        ( (void(__CLRCALL_OR_CDECL *)(void *))(((_ptiddata)ptd)->_initaddr) )
            ( ((_ptiddata)ptd)->_initarg );

        _endthread();
    } `

Well, time to search the web. Ty for your help so far Red Alert